# Open energyoptions with autohotkey

Tags: windows, autohotkey, keymapping

I am currently experimenting with AutoHotkey and wanted to create a script that opens up the windows energy options. But since there is no path or anything I can use, I simply can't figure out how to do it. Anyone knows a solution or has done this before?

Answer (score 1):

Or, to get there more directly, try:

```
Run, powercfg.cpl
```

But, depending on what you want to accomplish, there is a command line tool `powercfg.exe` that may have a function you can exploit: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff794903

`powercfg [-l] [-q] [-x] [-changename] [-duplicatescheme] [-d] [-deletesetting] [-setactive] [-getactivescheme] [-setacvalueindex] [-setdcvalueindex] [-h] [-a] [-devicequery] [-deviceenablewake] [-devicedisablewake] [-import] [-export] [-lastwake] [-?] [-aliases] [-setsecuritydescriptor] [-getsecuritydescriptor][-requests][-requestsoverride][-energy][-waketimers]`

Answer (score 0):

You want to simulate what you would do with the keyboard - that is the whole idea of AutoHotKey.

The following code uses Control-p to open the energy options:

```
^p::
    KeyWait Control ; wait for the control key to be released 
    Send {LWin} ; send windows key
    Send Power Options ; type in what you want to load
    Sleep 300 ; waits for start menu to filter - adjust this number
    Send {Enter} ; select power options
return
```